# What is the most efficient way to pass a local variable address to extended inline ASM for ARM-v7?

Tags: embedded, inline-assembly, local-variables, armv7

Consider this code snippet:

```
__asm volatile (
            "   MOVW    R0, #0x0000     \n\t"
            "   MOVT    R0, #0x3004     \n\t"
            "   LDRSH   R1, [R0, #12]   \n\t"
         ⋮
)
```

This is the hard-coded way for loading what's stored at address 0x30040000 + 12 into R1.

I understand I can use a list of input and output variables and a clobber list. So if I use something like this:

```
int16_t localVar = 10;

__asm volatile (
            "   <some code with %[lv]> \n\t"
            "   LDRSH   R1, ???        \n\t"
         ⋮
            :  [lv] "r" (localVar)
         ⋮
)
```

What do I need to replace `<some code with %[lv]>` and/or the question marks with so that I end up with value 10 in register R1? I generally don't know how to do this. It would be great to learn the most efficient way for ARM-v7 in terms of execution time needed.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Both these asm statements are pointless and unsafe, not telling the compiler about the load result in `r1` as an output operand.  And pointless because you could do them just as well without asm at all, just use a `volatile int16_t*` that you dereference.  If you want a local var's value, why not ask for the var's value in an `"r"` input, instead of inefficiently forcing the compiler to store it so you can use an `"m"` memory input or whatever?

Comment: I am trying to convert C code in an interrupt routine to assembler code and I rather than doing it from scratch, I want to do it step by step. With this way of reading a variable, I felt it was easier to do.

Comment: GNU C inline asm is hard enough to use; I'd recommend just using `"r"` to get the variable's value in a register, unless you also need to modify it.  (In which case `"+m"` will expand that operand to an addressing mode you can read and write, or use `"+r"` to get a reg you can read and write.)